# code visualization in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was looking at a python code visualization tool (http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) that nicely draws a model with its functions:

[image]

I am interested in having something similar for django projects where models could be visualized exactly like this, instead of just one class all the models could be visualized with a nice graphic. However graphic does not mean class or any uml diagram.

Any pointers how to approach this? Any existing libraries that already achieve this or if there are none, what could be important to look at to build one?

Answer (score 2):

[django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) is probably what you need. Try command *graph_models* to generate models visualization.

Comment: django-extensions graph models only generate more less like class diagram which I tried. I am more interested in representing an object with its attributes and possible methods as in above example.